# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: The 'listener' parameter must be a function

Tags: javascript, функции, асинхронность

Вызываю функцию addListener из библиотеки WebMidi, третий параметр называется 'listener'. Требуется, чтобы этот параметр был функцией (В моём случае это `readByKey(keyPress)`)

```
 WebMidi.inputs[0].addListener('noteon', "all", readByKey(keyPress));

async function readByKey(keyPress) { //Key press handler (Gets data about the key pressed and reads project file)
    await $.getJSON("project.json", function (proj) { //Getting the project
        project = proj;
        console.log(project);
        });
    var frame = 1; //Resetting to the 1st frame (because we want to read from the first frame, not some random value)
    if (typeof keyPress != null && typeof project != null) { //Making sure everything is downloaded
        do { //
            switch (project["1"]["1"][keyPress.note.number][frame].act) { //Checks the action on some [frame] and acts accordingly
                case "an": //"an" stands for "animation"
                    output.playNote(project["1"]["1"][keyPress.note.number][frame].n, { rawVelocity: 1, velocity: project["1"]["1"][keyPress.note.number][frame].v, time: project["1"]["1"][keyPress.note.number][frame].t });
                    break;
            }
            frame++;
        } while (project["1"]["1"]["11"][frame].act !== "sa") // "an" stands for "animation", "sa" for "stop animation" 
    }
}
```

Я не понимаю почему моя функция не считается функцией. Есть идеи?

Comment: Может дело в асинхронности? Попробуйте переписать функцию `readByKey` на синхронный лад.

Comment: Параметр должен был функцией, а Вы передаёте туда результат вызова функции `readByKey`, то есть Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция с модификатором `async` возвращает `Promise`, который не является функцией.

Так как идет попытка предать его в качестве обработчика и появляется указанная ошибка.

Вместо этого, можно обернуть вызов в функцию, например:

```
WebMidi.inputs[0].addListener('noteon', "all", ()=>readByKey(keyPress));
```